# Should null set $(\emptyset)$ be included in the ordered pair when finding the cartesian product of two power sets?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Let $A=\{a\}$ and $B=\{b\}$.
$$P(A)\times P(B)=?$$
Now, the first step here is to obviously find the power sets of $A$ and $B$, so as to simplify the problem:
$$=\{\emptyset,\{a\}\}\times \{\emptyset,\{b\}\}$$
Now my question here is, when taking the cartesian product of these two sets here, will we include the null sets $(\emptyset)$ in the ordered pairs that are formed, as in:
$$=\{(\emptyset,\emptyset),(\emptyset,\{b\}),(\{a\},\emptyset),(\{a\},\{b\})\}$$
or would something else be the answer because null set is practically an empty set?

I do know that $\emptyset \times X=\emptyset$ where $X$ is any set; however, I think the above case is different in the sense that we have a null set within another set in the case above, and therefore, we aren't directly finding the cartesian product with null set but instead, with a set that contains null set as an element.

Comment: I doubt the exercise was meant to ascertain your ability to recognize that "null set is practically an empty set", whatever that may mean.

Comment: Yes, $\emptyset$ will be a coordinate of some pairs in the Cartesian product of two powersets. It's written "\emptyset".

Comment: Your reasoning is right.

Comment: You are correct.  $(\emptyset,\emptyset) \ne \emptyset$